# A way to detect default value not changed and cleaning up code . Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, contains

I have been coding in `Kotlin` for a few months now. I still have a lot to learn I know this. I have a piece of code that in my head should work. I am not happy with how it looks, and I feel it can be done in a better way.

Can someone please help show me the right way of doing what I am currently want to do.

```
 btnSend.setOnClickListener {
            var x =0

             var exceptionList = ArrayList(partsList.filter { (it.Exception) })

             exceptionList.forEach {
                 if(it.EReason.contains("Select a reason")){x=1}}

             if( x == 1 ){
                 val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                 builder.setMessage("Please select a reason for the current exception")
                 //    Toast.makeText(context,"Data capture canceled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                 builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                 builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel"){dialogInterface , which ->
                 }
                 val alertDialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()

                 alertDialog.setCancelable(true)
                 alertDialog.show()

             }else{ ...
```

The aim of the code is to look trough my `arraylist` and find out if one of the fields `exceptionlist[x].EReason` still contains the default value and has not been changed. The field is populated by a `spinner` inside my `Recylerview`. `it.Exception` is a `checkbox` that filters my array to only the selected items.

Comment: It will help if you add the types of your variables here.

Comment: Also please note that the Kotlin coding standard (which practically everyone follows) uses camelCase for properties, functions, and variables (with an exception for compile-time constants which can be in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE); only classes are in PascalCase. So `it.Exception` and `it.EReason` are confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably rewrite this part:

```
var x =0

var exceptionList = ArrayList(partsList.filter { (it.Exception) })

exceptionList.forEach {
    if(it.EReason.contains("Select a reason")){x=1}}
if( x == 1 ){
```

as:

```
if (partsList.any { it.Exception && it.EReason.contains("Select a reason") })
```

Comment: A further tweak: replace `it.EReason.contains("Select a reason")` with `"Select a reason" in it.EReason`.